# Is it important to close PdfRenderer and when

Tags: android, pdfrenderer, android-pdf-api

I am using [`PdfRenderer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) in my app. In this app a user can open a PDF file and browse it. He can open another PDF file in the same session.

I just noticed, that I don't close it at all after use or before opening a new PDF. I just do the following:

```
mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
```

In [the Google example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-PdfRendererBasic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/pdfrendererbasic/PdfRendererBasicFragment.java) though the PdfRenderer is always closed after use.

```java
if (null != mCurrentPage) 
  mCurrentPage.close();
mPdfRenderer.close();
mFileDescriptor.close();
```

Is it important to call [`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer#close()) before opening a new PDF?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This is a general answer will cover all the scenarios including yours**

Well in general practice, you need to free up resources that are bound to your task, to be more precise **`Non-preemptive`** resources, it is considered to be best practice but, to remove the worker thread from the pool isn't extremely crucial nowadays, In short, for your answer

1. If you want to employ best practices you can do that
2. If you don't then when the application closes **`Garbage Cleaner`** will do your task for you when there will be a need of resources, or when the cleanup is scheduled

**When to Clean Resources or Close `worker Threads`**

1. When you want to close the application
2. When you need other tasks and you know that that task will take up a lot of resources and to make your application efficient you really wanted to do that.
3. When you want to Leave your application **`onPause()`**, your application for a moment (considered to be best practice but most developers don't do that, because some times, those process may take more resources on restarting because of a bundle processing[many processes may start on **`onStart()`** ])

for your question's answer, I hope the above statement might clarify everything.